# SQLite and regular expressions

Tags: regex, sqlite

I have a column in SQLite which contains strings such as:

`equal_to#1 capable#4 adequate_to#1`

I would like to get the following results:

`equal_to, capable, adequate_to`

I'm trying to get it working with replace but with no luck, perhaps someone might help me with some regex?

Comment: If you want to get help, please add details of what you tried, what the result was and what you expected instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [substr and instr](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html)

```
select substr("equal_to#1", 0, instr("equal_to#1", '#'))
```

output:

```
equal_to
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex should be something like this:

```
/#\d+/g
```

[here is an example](https://regex101.com/r/nJ2nL5/1)